# Creating replicated gluster volume always gives Distributed-Replicate volume

Tags: kubernetes, storage, nfs, glusterfs

Peace upon you,
I am trying to create a replicated gluster volume but always it gives me Distributed-Replicate volume
i followed the following commands

## Pool Peers

```
root@tiny1:~# gluster peer status
Number of Peers: 2

Hostname: userver
Uuid: c9e26a34-7aa9-47d2-a142-3db62d96bf9d
State: Peer in Cluster (Connected)

Hostname: huserver
Uuid: 6e88d282-8a3a-4e9f-a46f-427095a3d870
State: Peer in Cluster (Connected)
```

## Creating Replicated Voulume

### Creating Replicated volume of three 3 replicas

`gluster volume create glustervolume replica 3 userver:/gfs/brick1 tiny1:/gfs/brick2 huserver:/gfs/brick3 force`

### Gives a Distributed-Replicate volume rather than a Replicated one

````
gluster volume info ```

Volume Name: glustervolume
Type: Distributed-Replicate
Volume ID: c3da2300-8673-46e1-a47f-e692b2bfcf67
Status: Created
Snapshot Count: 0
Number of Bricks: 1 x 3 = 3
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: userver:/gfs/brick1
Brick2: tiny1:/gfs/brick2
Brick3: huserver:/gfs/brick3
Options Reconfigured:
cluster.granular-entry-heal: on
storage.fips-mode-rchecksum: on
transport.address-family: inet
nfs.disable: on
performance.client-io-threads: off
````

### Creating Replicated volume of two 2 replicas

```
gluster volume create glustervolume replica 2 tiny1:/gfs/brick1 userver:/gfs/brick2 force
```

### Gives a Distributed-Replicate volume rather than a Replicated one

```
gluster volume info  

Volume Name: glustervolume
Type: Distributed-Replicate
Volume ID: de220e55-4dbb-454b-a041-30cc6ba4021b
Status: Created
Snapshot Count: 0
Number of Bricks: 1 x 2 = 2
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: tiny1:/gfs/brick1
Brick2: userver:/gfs/brick2
Options Reconfigured:
cluster.granular-entry-heal: on
storage.fips-mode-rchecksum: on
transport.address-family: inet
nfs.disable: on
performance.client-io-threads: off
```

Answer (score 0):

Your volume type is `Distributed-Replicate` where is should be `Replicate`, when you are using the `replica` option it only indicate the number of `replicas` to be created, not the type of volume

Just use the `replicate` volume instead of the `replica` option, like this:

```
gluster volume create glustervolume replicateica 3 userver:/gfs/brick1 tiny1:/gfs/brick2 huserver:/gfs/brick3 force
```

Comment: That's didn't work because the word 'replicate' is wrong and in the official docs they have mentionned only the word 'replica'   https://docs.gluster.org/en/main/Administrator-Guide/Setting-Up-Volumes/#creating-replicated-volumes .  To create a replicated volume

Create a trusted storage pool.

Create the replicated volume:

# gluster volume create [replica ] [transport tcp | rdma | tcp,rdma]

For example, to create a replicated volume with two storage servers:


```# gluster volume create test-volume replica 2 transport tcp server1:/exp1 server2:/exp2```

Comment: If you solved your problem you should post an answer and accept it

Comment: No i didn't solve it yet.

Answer (score 0):

From the provided information, it is observed that you have 3 VMs with names **userver**,**huserver** and **tiny1**. By using the `gluster peer status` command it is observed that the peer status is active between **userver**,**huserver** and **tiny1**.

The below command is used for creating a replicated volume of three 2 replicas.

> gluster volume create glustervolume replica 2 tiny1:/gfs/brick1
> userver:/gfs/brick2 force

But the output is showing as **Distributed-Replicate** instead of **Replica** in **volume type**. To overcome this situation,please update the keyword **brick1** in both the VMs **tiny1** and **userver** as follows:

> gluster volume create glustervolume replica 2 tiny1:/gfs/brick1
> userver:/gfs/brick1 force

Note that the information needs to be replicated into the same kind of file (example :  brick1) in both the VMs as it will be easy to access or do any changes when required from the client's perspective.

Once the volume is created please run the below command to check the volume type.

> gluster volume info

Hope the above information is useful to you.

Also you can refer to the [article](https://blog.devgenius.io/replica-volume-in-glusterfs-b05324ce1b6f) written by **Schaffung** for more information.

Comment: did't work always it gives me the same type Distributed-Replicate, also i have flowwed that article before and it gives the same issue too thanks

Answer (score 0):

## SOLVED

#### By changing cluster  nodes configuration

### Old configuration

```
`node1: unbuntu server 20.04 gluster v 11`
`node2: unbuntu server 20.04 gluster v 11`
`node3: unbuntu server 22.04 gluster v 11`
```

Gluster was installed specifying the version 11 by adding ppa to all nodes

### New configuration

```
`node1: unbuntu server 22.04 gluster v 10.1`
`node2: unbuntu server 22.04 gluster v 10.1`
`node3: unbuntu server 22.04 gluster v 10.1`
```

Gluster was installed after upgrading nodes ubuntu to the same last version and then using the command

```
`apt install glusterfs-server`
```

without specifying the version and by default the same 10.1 version installed on all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a gluster cli bug in version 11.
For more information check the github issue below:

https://github.com/gluster/glusterfs/issues/4107

https://github.com/mohit84/glusterfs/commit/617fa5d2763e668ed85310c14e160d1c032d7c0c